# rxjs update the list in all components after create method

Tags: angular, rxjs, subject

I have a read function that returns a Subject, I subscribe and get a list of all entries in the component, but after the create method, I need to reload the page to see the changes, how can I update the list in the component without reloading the page?
component:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
this._bs.read({}).subscribe((birds: Bird) => {
  this.birds = birds
})
```

service:

```
create(doc: Document = this.new()): Subject<Document> {
if (Object(doc)._id && Object(doc).keys.indexOf(this._id) === -1) {
  return this.update(doc);
}
else {
  const sub = this._http.post(this._url + '/create', doc);
  this._reads.push(sub)
  return sub;
 }
}
read(opts: CrudOptions = {} as CrudOptions): any {
const sub = this._http.get(this._url + '/get');
  return sub;
}
```

Comment: angular's change detection should handle that, you just have to print birds in the template

Comment: i have a function in ts:
get rows(): Bird[] {
    return this.birds
}
and html:
<wtable
 title="Birds"
 [columns]="columns"
 [config]="config"
 [rows]="rows"
></wtable>
but it only works after page reload

Comment: can you please add some more code? like you didn't added your subject function code.